# Database Schema -Images in separate tables?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema

I'm pretty new to web development and i'm creating a local guide app. Currently, I have the following table in the database:

**Organization Table**

```
Organization_Id(PK)
name
description
site
category_id
```

**Description**

- organization: entity that describes a merchant
- organization profile: page with organization's details (name, description, site, cover header_image, profile_image, detail_images)

  - header_image: organizations cover image
  - profile_image: organizations logo image
  - detail_images: images of the organization building

**Relationships**

An Organization has_one profile_image, has_one header_image, has_many details_images.

**Question**

What is the best aproach in terms of normalization to accomplish that?

1. Add one column for the profile_image and another to header_image in Organization table.
2. Create one table ProfileImage, other table HeaderImage with one_to_one relationship to Organization table and eventually another DetailImage table with one_to_many relationship.
3. Create an Image table to store all the images paths table with a column image_type (profile, header, details) using a one_to_many relationship.
4. Other option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the first option.

- Create two columns, one for profile image, one for header image.
- Store the path

You shouldn't be creating new tables for 1:1 relations. For both header and profile you want to store *at most* one image. That's what columns are for.

Even better. Normalize them all to the same format and appropriate sizes and save them in  `pkid/header.png`, `pkid/profile.png` and then just make boolean flags `has_image_header` `has_image_profile` If you don't want to hardcode that path in the app, and you'd rather hardcode it in the database do it with a function,

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_path(pkid int, imgtype text)
RETURNS text
AS $$
  SELECT '/' || pkid::text || '/' || imgtype || '.png';
$$ LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;

SELECT get_path(432, 'header');
    get_path     
-----------------
 /432/header.png
(1 row)
```